# Cant change java button color after resetting button array

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Im creating a program in which I must from time to time reset a button Array and display it on a jPanel. The function below adds the jButtons to my panel and displays them perfectly the first time that it is called, but from then on, every time I call it (after emptying the jButton array and applying .removeAll() to the panel) it wont let me change the background color of the jButton. Some assistance to help me find out why this is would be great, thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Luis
 */
public class MineSweeper extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    int int_dim = 11;
    int int_cellsShown = 0;
    JButton[][] arr_btnField = new JButton[int_dim][int_dim];
    int[][] arr_solution = new int[int_dim][int_dim];
    Color[] clr_palette = {Color.white, new Color(0X00, 0X94, 0XFF), new Color(0X00, 0X26, 0XFF), new Color(0X00, 0XAA, 0X0A), Color.red, Color.MAGENTA, new Color(0XFF, 0X00, 0X00), new Color(0X9B, 0X00, 0X00)};
    boolean bool_change = false;
    boolean bool_won = false;
    boolean bool_firstround = false;

javax.swing.border.Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 1, true);

MenuBar menu_bar;
Menu menu;
MenuItem optionNew;
//boolean[][] arr_boolShowed=new boolean[int_dim][int_dim];
int int_mines = 8;
ArrayList<Integer> arl_field = new ArrayList<Integer>();
JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel();

//ArrayList<Boolean> arl_boolShowed = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public MineSweeper() throws FontFormatException, IOException {

    resetGame();

    //JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    this.getContentPane().add(jpanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setTitle("Minesweeper");
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(500, 500);

    menu_bar = new MenuBar();
    menu = new Menu("File");
    optionNew = new MenuItem("Win");
    optionNew.addActionListener(this);
    menu.add(optionNew);
    menu_bar.add(menu);
    this.setMenuBar(menu_bar);
}

public void resetGame() {
    jpanel.removeAll();
    arl_field.clear();

    arr_btnField = new JButton[int_dim][int_dim];
    arr_solution = new int[int_dim][int_dim];
    bool_change = false;
    bool_won = false;
    //arl_field = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_solution.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr_solution[i].length; j++) {
            arr_solution[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, int_dim));//if(bool_firstround==false)jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,int_dim));

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_btnField.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr_btnField[i].length; j++) {
            arr_btnField[i][j] = new JButton();////if(bool_firstround==false)arr_btnField[i][j] = new JButton();//arl_field.get(i*int_dim+j)+"");
            arr_btnField[i][j].setText("");
            arr_btnField[i][j].setBackground(new Color(0X00, 0X94, 0XFF));
            arr_btnField[i][j].setBorder(border);
            arr_btnField[i][j].setForeground(clr_palette[1]);
            arr_btnField[i][j].addMouseListener(listener);
            arr_btnField[i][j].setFocusable(false);
            jpanel.add(arr_btnField[i][j]);
        }
    }

    jpanel.revalidate();
    jpanel.repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new MineSweeper();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    });
}

MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_btnField.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr_btnField[i].length; j++) {
                if (e.getSource() == arr_btnField[i][j]) {
                    if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                        labelText(i, j);
                    }
                    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                        arr_btnField[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
                    }
                    //bool_won=false;
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if (bool_won == true)
            gameWon();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

};

public void labelText(int i, int j) {
    if (bool_won == false) {
        arr_btnField[i][j].setText("1");
        arr_btnField[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
        if (arr_btnField[i][j].getBorder() == border) {
            int_cellsShown++;
            System.out.println("Cells shown: " + int_cellsShown);
            if (int_cellsShown >= (int_dim * int_dim - int_mines)) {
                bool_won = true;
            }
        }
        if (bool_won == false)
            arr_btnField[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 1, true));
    }
}

public void gameWon() {
    int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You Won! Do you want to start a new game?", "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        bool_won = false;
        int_cellsShown = 0;
        resetGame();
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int_cellsShown = 0;
    int_dim++;
    resetGame();


     for (int i = 0; i < arr_btnField.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr_btnField[i].length; j++) {
                arr_btnField[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Display after the first time:
[image: Display after the first time]

Display after the second time:
[image: Display after the second time]

Comment: I can't give a full decent answer as you've not yet posted a valid [mcve], but I will suggest that you **not** remove all the buttons and add new ones, but rather when resetting your array, simply change the state of your current JButtons back to the initial state.

Comment: In other words, if you want better and more complete answers, answers that actually solve your problem, please post a more complete question, one with a valid [mcve] (please read the link).

Comment: Also, do you reset your clr_palette ArrayList and your int_dim int field before calling this code? Also, please don't ignore comments. Why should we bother looking at your code if you're just going to  ignore what we suggest?

Comment: I have updated  the post to show more of the whole method Im using to reset the program. Its a minesweeper. I too would not like to erase the buttons, but it is something that I probably should do since the player should be able to specify the amount of rows (int_dim) he wants. clr_palette is just for the foreground (which still works) and I dont reset it.

Comment: When you dynamically add components to a JPanel of a visible GUI you need to invoke `revalidate()` on the panel, before the repaint() to make sure the layout manager has been invoked and all the components are given a proper size/location.

Comment: I invoke .revalidate in the fourth line of the method. The displayed panel is not jpanel, the displayed panel is jpanel2, thats why I assign jpanel2 to the value of jpanel in the end of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the updated information, and you've gotten answer it seems, but again, if the answer doesn't solve your problem, please (again) do consider creating and posting a valid [mcve]. This is not your entire program, but a much smaller one that only has enough code to compile, run and demonstrate your problem. Yes, this would require a **lot** of effort from you, both creating a very small program that runs **and** one with the error, but this would require you to isolate the error. Often this process reveals the problem directly to you. If it doesn't it would help us greatly.

Comment: I've tried to create my own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the code that you've posted, you can see it here: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/ephUBNyY), but as you can see, reset in this example works fine, suggesting that code found elsewhere is your problem. Keep working on isolating the problem for without doing that first, you (and we) won't find a solution.

Comment: Im sorry it took so long, but I just posted compilable code with the problem that is happening to me. If you go to "File" and "Win", you will see the effects of winning the game and therefore resetting the button array, which leads to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I invoke .revalidate in the fourth line of the method.

That doesn't do anything since there on no components added to the panel. The revalidate() needs to be done AFTER the components have been added.

> The displayed panel is not jpanel, the displayed panel is jpanel2, thats why I assign jpanel2 to the value of jpanel in the end of the method.

You can't just change a reference and expect the components to be moved from one panel to another.

The components need to be added to the panel that is added to the GUI.

Edit:

First of all Swing components start with "J". Don't use AWT components (MenuBar, Menu, MenuItem) in a Swing application.

The problem is your LAF:

```
new MineSweeper();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

The components are created with the current LAF. When you first create the game, the default LAF is used to create all the buttons (and other components). This LAF allows you to change the background color of the buttons.

However, then you change the LAF. So when you reset the game board the buttons are now created with the System LAF. This LAF apparently does not allow you to change the background color of the button.

This should be easy to test. Create a GUI:

```
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

JButton button = new JButton("testing");
button.setBackground(Color.RED);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add( button );
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
frame.setVisible( true );
```

First test the code as above to see if the background of the button changes.

Then uncomment the LAF change and retest.

A possible solution so you are not dependent on the LAF is to use an Icon to represent the background color of the button. Then you can center any text on top of the Icon. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorIcon implements Icon
{
    private Color color;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public ColorIcon(Color color, int width, int height)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getIconWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public int getIconHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(2, 2) );

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Icon icon = new ColorIcon(Color.RED, 50, 50);
            JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
            label.setText("" + i);
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            panel.add(label);
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried revalidate() at the end just like you said and assigned jpanel as the panel being displayed, it still isn't working I've tried lots of different things, and everything seems to work fine, the only problem is that I cant change the background color of the jButton.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I had been changing everything in my code except for the main method (silly me).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I too just noticed, that the problem is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new MineSweeper();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If you comment out the UIManager line, your code works. This line is only valid *after* the GUI has been created, and so doesn't take effect until new components are created. Note that I was working on minimizing your code to discover this, and was cutting out code to see what caused the problem until this was all that was left.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MineSweeper extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final Color BTN_COLOR = new Color(0X00, 0X94, 0XFF);
    int int_dim = 11;
    JButton[][] arr_btnField = new JButton[int_dim][int_dim];

    JMenuBar menu_bar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem optionNew;
    JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();

    public MineSweeper() {
        resetGame();
        this.getContentPane().add(jpanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setTitle("Minesweeper");

        menu_bar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

        optionNew = new JMenuItem("Win");
        optionNew.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        optionNew.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(optionNew);
        menu_bar.add(menu);
        this.setJMenuBar(menu_bar);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void resetGame() {
        jpanel.removeAll();
        arr_btnField = new JButton[int_dim][int_dim];
        jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, int_dim));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_btnField.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr_btnField[i].length; j++) {
                arr_btnField[i][j] = new JButton();
                arr_btnField[i][j].setBackground(BTN_COLOR);
                jpanel.add(arr_btnField[i][j]);
            }
        }
        jpanel.revalidate();
        jpanel.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        resetGame();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MineSweeper();
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, next time I encounter a problem I will try to reduce the code as much as I can.